# Adding and Removing Artists while using FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, simulation

I am trying to animate a simulation of particles moving in 2D. Particles can combine to form new particles.

I have a Particle class (with typical particle info like mass, radius, position, velocity) and a Simulation class. When a particle is initialized it automatically creates its own Circle patch and stores it in its circle variable. I begin by adding particles to the simulation:

```
 sim = Simulation()
 for _ in range(num_particles):
   sim.addParticle(Particle(mass, radius, position, velocity))
```

The animation functions are all in the Simualtion class. The animation is started from Simulation.start_animation:

```
def start_animation(self):
  self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
  anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, init_func=self.init_anim, blit=True)
```

The animation initialization function adds the Circle patch of each initial particle to the axis and returns a list of the Circles:

```
def init_anim(self):
  for p in self.particles:
    self.ax.add_patch(p.circle)
  return [p.circle for p in self.particles]
```

The animation function increments the simulation time by some dt, then returns a list of all Circle patches:

```
def animate(self, i):
  self.advance_simulation(dt)
  return [p.circle for p in self.particles]
```

The advance_simulation function moves all the particles, then checks for collisions. If two particles collide, they combine to form a new particle. particle_merge(p1, p2) takes two particles and returns the particle that results from their merger.

```
def advance_simulation(self):
  # Move particles
  for p in self.particles:
    p.position += dt * p.velocity
    p.circle.center = p.position
  # Handle collisions
  colliders = set()
  newParticles = []
  for i, j in combinations(range(self.count), 2):
    p1 = self.particles[i]
    p2 = self.particles[j]
    if p1.overlaps(p2):
      colliders.update([i, j])
      p1.circle.set_visible(False) #I'd prefer to remove the Circle patch rather than turn invisible
      p2.circle.set_visible(False) #but I get a NotImplementedError
      new_particle = particle_merge(p1, p2)
      self.ax.add_patch(new_particle.circle)
      newParticles.append(new_particle)

  newParticles += [p for p in self.particles if not (p in colliders)]
  self.particles = newParticles
```

The animation initializes properly and the particles move as they should. The problem occurs as soon as two particles collide. The new circle patch appears and the old patches disappear, but the new patch doesn't move. I know that the new particle is in fact being simulated, because I can see the effect of its ghost on other particles.

Also, I would like to remove the patches corresponding to particles that have been removed, but when I call p.cirlcle.remove() for some particle p I get a NotImplementedError.

I first got the animation working without blitting, but redrawing hundreds of particles each frame is incredibly slow, so I really would like to get this working with blitting. I don't really know much about how FuncAnimation works though...

From what I understand, the init_anim function is supposed to return the list of Artists that were drawn/will be redrawn, which I'm pretty sure mine does. The animate function is likewise supposed to return a list of Artists that were modified or created. Since I return a list of the circles for every particle in the sim, I don't understand why my Circles added in the advance_simulation function aren't being updated in the animation.

Comment: So far the only fix I've found is to add a bunch of extra invisible circle patches in the init_anim function which I later make visible when new particles are created. The only problem is that I can't a priori know how many particles will be created so I have to make more invisible patches than the maximum amount I could need.

Comment: I would separate data and animation into two part, collect particle positions for every frame first, then do animation only for data. In this way, you will have faster animation updates.